# How to return a function resulted from alternate combining two lists of functions in Haskell programming?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In my Haskell course assignment, I want to cope a challenge which is essentially to catch on how to process lists of functions. The input consists of two such lists, lets say first of them is given as [A0..AN] and second one is told to be [B0..BN]. I need to return a single function that composes functions applying them so that functions alternate as nested function arguments inside an output function. In fact, it means the output like one:

G x = A0 (B0 (A1 (B1 (A2 (B2 (...AN (BN))))))

My primary solution doesn't work, there is code I've tried to start with:

```
funcCarnage :: [a -> a] -> [a -> a] -> (a -> a)
funcCarnage (x:xs) (y:ys) = extraFuncCarnage xs ys x 2 where
extraFuncCarnage bs fs gs n
    | length bs == 0 && length fs == 0 = gs  
    | odd n = extraFuncCarnage (tail bs) fs (gs $ head bs) (n + 1) 
    | otherwise = extraFuncCarnage bs (tail fs) (gs $ head fs) (n + 1)
```

Compilation fails with erro messages:

```
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ a -> a
  Expected type: a -> a
    Actual type: (a -> a) -> a -> a
* In the expression: extraFuncCarnage xs ys x 2
  In an equation for `funcCarnage':
      funcCarnage (x : xs) (y : ys)
        = extraFuncCarnage xs ys x 2
        where
            extraFuncCarnage bs fs gs n
              | length bs == 0 && length fs == 0 = gs
              | odd n = extraFuncCarnage (tail bs) fs (gs $ head bs) (n + 1)
              | otherwise = extraFuncCarnage bs (tail fs) (gs $ head fs) (n + 1)

* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t1 ~ t -> t1
  Expected type: [t] -> [t] -> t1 -> a1 -> t -> t1
    Actual type: [t] -> [t] -> (t -> t1) -> a1 -> t -> t1
* In an equation for `funcCarnage':
      funcCarnage (x : xs) (y : ys)
        = extraFuncCarnage xs ys x 2
        where
            extraFuncCarnage bs fs gs n
              | length bs == 0 && length fs == 0 = gs
              | odd n = extraFuncCarnage (tail bs) fs (gs $ head bs) (n + 1)
              | otherwise = extraFuncCarnage bs (tail fs) (gs $ head fs) (n + 1)
```

It's some obscure complaint, so I'm confused how to proceed with solving. How do I have to fix both type errors?

Comment: Hint: your function is much more complex than it needs to be. Try rewriting it as `funcCarnage (f:fs) (g:gs) = \x -> f (g (funcCarnage fs gs x))` and go from there.

Comment: @bradrn, thank you a lot for your response. Now, I just gonna be sure to have it caught right: will this recursion stop once second array is out or recursion to be stopped with some additional code here? (Yes, I see clear it was completely wrong what I did before. The recursion remains an only point I'm still feeling some confusion to get).

Comment: I would do this in two steps.  First, write a function to interleave two lists `interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`; second, apply a list of functions to an argument `applyMany :: [a -> a] -> a -> a`.  Then the function you are looking for is easy to write.

Comment: @HaskellSteamMachine You will need to write some more lines to stop the recursion — otherwise you will get an error about unmatched patterns when you try to run `funcCarnage`. For instance, you could write `funcCarnage _ [] = id` to stop recursing when the second list is empty. Since each list can have either some elements or none, you have four cases to consider: `funcCarnage (f:fs) (g:gs)` (which I already covered), `funcCarnage [] _`, `funcCarnage _ []` and `funcCarnage [] []`. But since the last three cases should be treated the same way, you can just combine them all into a single…

Comment: …`funcCarnage _ _` case. This will give you a function divided into two cases: `funcCarnage (f:fs) (g:gs)` (the recursive case) and `funcCarnage _ _` (where the recursion ends). Of course, this changes if you want to end the recursion at a different point — you will need to carefully think about what you want `funcCarnage` to do when it uses up one list entirely, and then implement it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this

```
funcCarnage :: [a -> a] -> [a -> a] -> (a -> a)
funcCarnage xs ys = foldl1 (.) $ zipWith (.) xs ys
```

Not convinced if I used the right fold.

Applying

```
funcCarnage [(+) 10, (*) 2] [(+) 3, (*) 5] $ 9
```

gives `103`.

See  [ZVON](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/I_o.html) for some info about `(.)`.

Comment: Folding right or left, since `(.)` is associative, will produce the same result as long as the list is finite. Still, I'd prefer `foldr (.) id` since that handles the empty list case and is lazier (`foldr (.) id (const 5 : undefined) 1` returns `5`, without accessing the rest of the list which is `undefined`).

Comment: Even though I kindly appreciate views shared by @bradrn, luqui (both helped me catch on the matter I was tangled with), your solution is pretty workable and useful for getting some ideas about function composition to solve cases like that. Thanks to everybody, now things stand more obvious to go on as tuned as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can first merge the two lists and then do a right fold.

```
import Control.Applicative(ZipList(..))

funcCarnage fs gs = foldr (.) id list
  where
    list = concat $ getZipList $ (\x y -> [x, y]) <$> ZipList fs <*> ZipList gs
```

Comment: or simply: `funcCarnage fs gs = appEndo $ foldMap Endo $ zipWith (.) fs gs`

Comment: or `funcCarnage fs gs x = foldr ($) x $ concat $ transpose [fs,gs]`.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers discuss how to use library functions as building blocks to create your function. I think it might also be interesting to see how to write the recursion yourself; in this case it's particularly simple. I will follow luqui's excellent suggestion in the comments of first writing a function to interleave two lists, then composing all the functions in the result.

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
interleave [] ys = ys

compose :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
compose [] = id
compose (f:fs) = f . compose fs
```

Then your function can run these two in sequence:

```
carnage :: [a -> a] -> [a -> a] -> a -> a
carnage fs gs = compose (interleave fs gs)
```

Later, as you get more advanced, you may be able to notice certain common looping structures in the above code. The `compose` one in particular is quite a standard "shape" of iteration: do something to combine a particular element with the result of making a recursive call. This shape is so common that we have a standard library function to encapsulate it. `foldr` takes the combining function (that combines a single element with the result of a recursive call) and the base case result as arguments, then does the iteration, so:

```
compose :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
compose = foldr (.) id
```

The loop in `interleave` is a less common shape, although it does come up occasionally in various circumstances. One way is to think about it as a zip; or, you can observe that matrix transposition is essentially an arbitrary-arity zip and reuse that operation. So:

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave xs ys = concat (transpose [xs, ys])
```

At this point, the function implementations for `compose` and `interleave` are so short, that you might consider inlining them if you don't find the names to be an important part of the explanatory power of the code. So:

```
carnage :: [a -> a] -> [a -> a] -> a -> a
-- was: carnage fs gs = compose (interleave fs gs)
carnage fs gs = foldr (.) id (concat (transpose [fs, gs]))
```

Idiomatically, Haskell programmers typically prefer function composition chains to nested parentheses:

```
carnage fs gs = foldr (.) id . concat . transpose $ [fs, gs]
```

To my experienced eye, this looks compact and readable; I would stop there.